# count a group with if condition in SAS

Tags: sas

I have mutiple MID's and for each MID the variable Method_ALL= 1 then count the MID in SAS? can I do this in data step instead proc sql?

Input

```
MID.   Method_ALL
334.      1
334.      0
334.      1
334.      1
334.      1
```

Output

```
MID.   Method_ALL.   Count_REC     Match_Count.    
334.      0.             5.             4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a data step instead of SQL, but SQL would be more straight-forward. Here's how you do it with both.

SQL: we will sum the boolean case where method_ALL = 1 to get a match count, then group it by MID. If method_ALL is only binary, then you simply need to sum this column. Otherwise, it's safer to do it using the method below.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select MID 
             , count(*) as Count_REC
             , sum( (method_ALL = 1) ) as Match_Count
        from have
        group by MID
    ;
quit;
```

Data step: We will do a row-by-row count for each MID group. At the end of each MID group, we will output the counts.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by mid;

    /* Reset counters at each MID group */
    if(first.mid) then do;
        Count_REC   = 0;
        Match_Count = 0;
    end;

    count_REC+1;
   
    if(Method_ALL = 1) then Match_Count+1;

    if(last.mid) then output;

    keep mid count_rec match_count;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing 2 solution since there were other conditions worked out in data step I need the logic data step. It worked perfectly as expected.